# Why is condition.notify_all wakes only one waiter?

Tags: python, coroutine, python-asyncio

I've tried to create a python async version of java's `CountDownLatch`

```
class CountDownLatch:
    def __init__(self, count=1):
        if count == 0:
            raise ValueError('count should be more than zero')
        self.count = count
        self.countdown_over = aio.Condition()

    async def countdown(self):
        with await self.countdown_over:
            print('decrementing counter')
            self.count -= 1
            print('count {}'.format(self.count))
            if self.count == 0:
                print('count is zero no more waiting')
                await aio.sleep(1)
                self.countdown_over.notify_all()

    async def wait(self):
        with await self.countdown_over:
            await self.countdown_over.wait()
```

Now I'm trying it.

```
In [2]: async def g(latch):
   ...:     await latch.wait()
   ...:     print('g')
   ...:

In [3]: async def f(latch):
   ...:     print('counting down')
   ...:     await latch.countdown()
   ...:     await g(latch)
   ...:

In [4]: def run():
   ...:     latch = CountDownLatch(2)
   ...:     loop = aio.get_event_loop()
   ...:     loop.run_until_complete(aio.wait((f(latch), f(latch))))
   ...:

In [5]: import asyncio as aio

In [6]: from new.tests.test_turnovers import CountDownLatch
```

And here's the output

```
counting down
decrementing counter
count 1
counting down
decrementing counter
count 0
count is zero no more waiting
g
```

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong here. The counter is created and decremented just fine. One coroutine even is notified and proceeded with it's task, but the second one is not for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Let `f1` be `f` called as the first one and let `f2` be `f` called as the second. The thing that should be noted is that even though you've used `async` keyword `f` function is **synchronous** until it hits `latch.wait()`. So we can actually easily debug what's going on:

1. `f1` fires.
2. `count` is decreased by `1`
3. `f1` enters `await self.countdown_over.wait()` and *context switch* happens
4. `f2` fires
5. `count` is decreased by `1`, `f2` enters `if` condition
6. `self.countdown_over.notify_all()` fires. All waiters are notified (note that at that point it is only `f1`).
7. `f2` enters `await self.countdown_over.wait()` and *context switch* happens
8. `f1` wakes up and leaves `.wait()` call

Note that step 7 happens **after** step 6. Thus `f2` is never notified.

Generally if you have multiple (green or not) threads that do notify and wait (in this order, synchronously) then at least one of them will always fail to proceed.